# Bash one liner to mask data in the file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a medium sized (~2000 lines) in which would like to mask data if the record char and record type matches

File Name: test.txt

[Bash one-liner to mask data in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624098/bash-one-liner-to-mask-data-in-file)

I wrote a sample script based on the above link and came up with below command ..

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\"\""} ($1$2$3==$recordchar && $12$13==$recordtype) {
for(i=$begin;i<=$end;i++) $i="X"}1' $file_name
```

Above command I have it in my shell script which is getting executed but not masking with XXX

Command seems to be working fine if I execute in shell CLI, but if I enter it in bash function then it seems like not picking up $1,$2 and end result not masking.

Sample test data:

```
SAR00000000560000000000000000000012345
```

in above sample data `recordchar = SAR` and `recordtype = 56` where `begin = 1` and `end = 5`

after running the script would like to see the data as

```
SAR000000005600000000000000000000XXXXX
```

in sed I could see it checks for first char but not sure how to check for second record type also .. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Additional information on above file..

- First 3 letters are always chars.
- number 56 is in fixed position.
- Length of the file varies across whole file.. from 10 upto 136
  the char to mask position also varies..

Hence only came up below one line which is in method mask() where I pass on `recordchar`, `recordtype`, begin and end..

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\"\""} ($1$2$3==$recordchar && $12$13==$recordtype) {
for(i=$begin;i<=$end;i++) $i="X"}1' $file_name
```

Sample Data: 2

```
SAR00000099652009110000060063803721586 3LOBO ABCDEF/GHIJKLMN                                                           05AUG98ADT
```

here `SAR` is the record and `65` is record type and char to be masked is A to N

Comment: Your samples are changed now and are un-clear(after editing), could you please do add them clearly, place your actual Input_file samples and your expected sample clearly for better understanding please.

Comment: What are `begin` and `end` values? Are these absolute character positions in each record?

Comment: And what's the expected output for _Sample Data: 2_?

Comment: Please spend sometime to edit your samples of input and expected output in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what is not clear in my samples.. I mentioned 2 sample and what I am trying to do and what I have tried so far. Recordchar is static SAR (always first 3 digit) and 65 is static always 13 and 14 pos.. and I have begin& end record which I would like to mask (X) .. so X needs to be repeated from being to end.. Please let me know if something is unclear. Thanks again for helping out.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative `awk` using all your predefined variables:

```
cat mask.awk

substr($0,1,3) == recordchar && substr($0,12,2) == recordtype {
   p = substr($0, 1, begin-1)          # substring before begin position
   c = substr($0, begin, end-begin+1)  # substring between begin and end positions
   s = substr($0, end + 1)             # substring after end position
   gsub(/./, "X", c)                   # replace each char by X between begin, end
   $0 = p c s                          # concat all parts
} 1
```

Run it:

```
awk -v recordchar='SAR' -v recordtype='56' -v begin=34 -v end=38 -f mask.awk file

SAR000000005600000000000000000000XXXXX
SAR00000099652009110000060063803721586 3LOBO ABCDEF/GHIJKLMN                                                           05AUG98ADT
```

And again:

```
awk -v recordchar='SAR' -v recordtype='65' -v begin=46 -v end=60 -f mask.awk file

SAR00000000560000000000000000000012345
SAR00000099652009110000060063803721586 3LOBO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                           05AUG98ADT
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.. mask.awk seems like running without syntax error but seems like it is calculating something from end of line and masking from end of string to back.. where in case, if possible I would like to mask desired begin to desired end .. Like in my command I have where to being and where to end .. "{for(i=$begin;i<=$end;"

Comment: So `begin` and `end` are absolute positions like `begin=34` and `end=38` in this record `SAR00000000560000000000000000000012345` ?

Comment: Thank you. It seems like working.. Will check few additional scenario.. One quick question - Is there a way I can add this as single line in my script function? instead to save mask.awk ?

Comment: Yes sure, you can use: `awk -v recordchar='SAR' -v recordtype='65' -v begin=46 -v end=60 'substr($0,1,3) == recordchar && substr($0,12,2) == recordtype { p = substr($0, 1, begin-1); c = substr($0, begin, end-begin+1); s = substr($0, end + 1); gsub(/./, "X", c); $0 = p c s;} 1' file`

Comment: Yes, I tried above and it worked inline in script..

Comment: Is there an alternative for above awk using sed?  or awk itself which will help to do inline replace in file.. currently it looks like I need to pass file each time as input and store it on different file. like currently. if I have do masking of 8 records then 8 files are created cmd  file > file1 then cmd file2> file 3

Comment: gnu awk can also do inline file change. Use `awk -i inplace ...`